# math.sqrt results in TypeError:'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm doing a homework assignment and want to fully train all the classes to what they are expected to do. I came across this TypeError which was really bugging me around.

This is for a little kids' test of health evaluation.
I've tried google, but that just gave me one big blob of code,
and I've tried deleting the `Power` class and of course, gave me an error.

The main loop(not finished):

```
pd = Power()
num = pd.calc_num()
cir_num = int(math.sqrt(num))**2
circles = []
filled = 0
while True:
    for i in range(math.sqrt(cir_num)-1):
        for j in range(math.sqrt(cir_num)-1):
            c = Circle(frame, cir_num)
            circles.append(c)
    ##drawing
    for c in circles:
        if c.stage == 'empty':
            c.draw_empty()
        elif c.stage == 'filled':
            c.draw_filled()
    avar = 0
    for c in circles:
        avar += c.num2
    filled += avar
```

The definition of the power class is:
like there is a number, and there is a function that takes 2 to the power of... the number.

The circle class is that there is a button. If the button stage is 'empty', I will draw the button with an empty circle. If a button with an empty circle is clicked, the button will have a filled circle that won't do anything.

This is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/roche/Documents/assignment.py", line 47, in <module>
    for i in range(math.sqrt(cir_num)-1):
TypeError: 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

And the tkinter size is weird:

```
root.geometry('750x750+0+0')
```

gives me a vertical rectangle and I was expecting a square window.
Thanks!

Comment: how would you interpret to to loop from, say 1 to 11.31?

Comment: Also, earlier in your code you have made the result of a square root an integer...

Comment: ok, all of you two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You twice use the expression

```
range(math.sqrt(cir_num)-1)
```

The result of `math.sqrt` is a float value, so you are trying to get the `range` of a float value. As the [documentation for range](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#range) states,

> The arguments to the range constructor must be integers (either built-in int or any object that implements the `__index__` special method).

So if you really want to use `range` and `math.sqrt` together, you must convert the float to an int. This is probably what you want:

```
range(int(math.sqrt(cir_num))-1)
```

As one of the comments implies, `range` demanding an integer makes sense. If you ask for `range(math.sqrt(5))`, how is the program to loop from `0` to `2.2361`? There is no obvious meaning for that, so Python requires to loop over only integer values. The `numpy` module does have the [arange function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and the [linspace function](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html#numpy.linspace), which can handle non-integer values, but the meaning of the ranges has been somewhat changed from Python's `range`.

Comment: @Song: What do you mean? You leave too much unexplained (like your purpose, the definition of `Power()` and `calc_num()`, etc.) for me to be sure what would solve your overall problem. But using my expression rather than yours should definitely remove the `'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` error. Did that message disappear?

Answer (score 1):

You are using *range* to mean much what it means in natural language, which is more or less *a segment of the real number line*, as in "temperature in the range 37.2C to 38.6C". But that is not what `range()` means in Python. In Python it means *a bunch of contiguous integers*. That is why you are getting complaints about the float you are calling it with.

Comment: I get what you are saying, but what is the solution?

Comment: To answer that I need to know what values you are expecting `i` to have in the loop `for i in range(...)`. It may seem obvious to you but...